# How to use an iterator to copy a list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, iterator

If I have a list, and I want to have a method that returns the list without exposing the actual list itself, what would be the best way to do that?

```
public class open {
    private List<Open> users;

    public open() {
        this.users = new ArrayList<Open>();
    }
    public List<Open> getUsers() {
      //return a copy of the list}
```

So basically I'd need a copy of the list... I'm guessing that using iterators might be the way to go, but is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of options.

You could use the copy constructor:

```
return new ArrayList<>(users);
```

This will explicitly copy the `List` and return the copy. I wouldn't recommend this unless you really need a mutable copy - it's `O(n)` obviously.

A much more efficient approach is to use the [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) utility class, this provides a way to return an immutable view:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(users);
```

As this is a view, return method is `O(1)` rather than `O(n)` so more efficient. It deals with ensuring that you cannot modify the `List`, neither via `add` & `remove` etc nor via, for example, `Iterator.remove`.

Answer (score 3):

It's unnecessary to create a copy of the list.  You can return an unmodifiable view of the list with [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-).

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(users);
```